# Get email attachments (.eml) using office rest api

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-api

I am trying to download email content as eml file. I am the following outlook api

> [https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{messageId}/$value](https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/%7BmessageId%7D/$value).

However, this api return the email as a string so I need to parse this string and construct eml formal file. I'm wondering if there any other way to download the email directly as eml file instead of constructing it.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt to solve your own problem

Comment: there's nothing to explain here, just I want instead of contructing mime by myself to find a way to download it using outlook api request